# Tag a different branch than master on pull request

Tags: github-actions

I'm new at github actions and there's something I clearly don't understand, so hoping for some help. I've inherited a repo with a workflow consisting of a number of steps, and while I'm getting the overall picture, there's also a part just not working.

### What I want to achieve

My workflow builds a number of containers and a binary. These are uploaded to different places, all with version number and tag matching. This works great for a release as everything is tagged properly and references each other. However, I want this to work for an unmerged pull-request as well - this would give the possibility to test things properly.

### The problem

The github repo is tagged, but it is always the HEAD of master getting tagged, also on pull requests. For pull requests, I expect the commit of the PR branch to get tagged - but nope.

The workflow below runs as I expect it to - the pre-release step runs for pull request actions, while the release steps runs when the pull request is merged. However, for each pull request action, the HEAD of master is tagged with the generated tag.

### Workflow

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - "master"

  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  tag:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    outputs:
      name: ${{ steps.generate_tag.outputs.name }}

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.sha }}

      - name: Generate tag name
        id: generate_tag
        run: echo "::set-output name=name::v$(date -d "$(git show -s --format=%ci)" +'%Y.%-m.%-d-%-H%M%S')"

  go:
    runs-on: macos-latest
    needs: [tag]
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.sha }}

      - name: Tag actual releases as releases
        if: "contains(github.ref, 'master')"
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config user.email noreply@github.com

          git tag "${{ needs.tag.outputs.name }}" -m "Version: ${{ needs.tag.outputs.name }}"
          git checkout "${{ needs.tag.outputs.name }}"
          git branch

      - name: Tag PRs as prerelease
        if: "!contains(github.ref, 'master')"
        run: |
          git config user.name "GitHub Actions"
          git config user.email noreply@github.com

          git tag "${{ needs.tag.outputs.name }}"
          git checkout "${{ needs.tag.outputs.name }}"
          git branch
```

Answer (score 1):

On Pull Request event trigger from any branch to master the `ref: ${{ github.sha }}` does not point to the last commit of that branch. Since you're using push and pull_request events for master and other branches then you should be able to just **remove the usage of ref during actions checkout step.**

Try the following step to checkout current branch code that generated the event. The following will be your branch latest commit on pull request, and it will be master after commit merged during the push event.

```
- uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
```

You can find more about [github actions here topics here](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLj7FiZ89RypSdCJaYXAH3WkGsMlB-xGg9)

Comment: Thanks - I'll try that. What's odd+interesting to me is that I've tried adding a `git push --tags` after the `git tag` - and that does actually seem to tag the correct/expected commit, and not master. Not sure where the code goes wrong